# Spring Data JPQL Could not extract resultset

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to get the number of entries where the score and date columns are in a given range, grouped by score intervals. Score intervals are determined by the given granularity. So the question I want to answer is: how many results are there, for the given time period, with scores between 0-25, 26-50, 56-75, etc... where in this case, the granularity would be 25.

The following native SQL query yields the desired results:

```
SELECT result.score, COUNT(*), ((score-1) DIV 25) AS eqclass FROM v_result AS result GROUP BY (eqclass);
```

I'd like to define a query method with my own query, using `@Query` annotation.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.ScoreDistribution(COUNT(scoreStatistics.score), (scoreStatistics.score - 1) / :granularity) FROM ScoreStatisticsEntity scoreStatistics WHERE start_date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY ((scoreStatistics.score - 1) / :granularity)")
List<ScoreDistribution> calculateDistributionByGranularity(@Param("startDate") DateTime startDate, @Param("endDate") DateTime endDate, @Param("granularity") int granularity);
```

`ScoreDistribution` is a simple bean, it is not an entity. `ScoreStatisticsEntity` however is an entity, and it is backed by a view table.

I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Hibernate API doc states:

```
public class SQLGrammarException extends JDBCException
```

> Implementation of JDBCException indicating that the SQL sent to the database server was invalid (syntax error, invalid object references, etc).

So, the question is: what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Shouldn't `WHERE start_date` be something like `WHERE scoreStatistics.startDate`?

Comment: Wow... such a long post for such a stupid mistake... please post this observation as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Just did, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE start_date` should be something like `WHERE scoreStatistics.startDate`